# Refreshing page on new nav duplicates filter

Tags: bug, new-nav

I have a saved filter for C++ questions that need answers. If I refresh the page while this filter tab is selected, it is duplicated and the new one is selected instead:

[image: With a nice hand-drawn circle]

The same happens if I just bookmark the page and then access it through the bookmark. When accessing through a bookmark(or refreshing), could the site detect I already have this filter, and then select it, instead of creating a new one?

Comment: I have this beahviour as well. For me it looks like it has to do with the plus signs that prevent matching the filter against the saved one. "Java" or "Swing" filters work as expected.